# Jmeter can get parameters?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

My question is - if I run a test via Jmeter, for example , if it's a site which enables you to book a flight, and you choose your source and destination when you record it.

Is it possible to pass different values to the destination field? I mean, maybe a txt file with some destinations and pass it to the Jmeter test and then, you will have some tests which each of them is running with a different destination?

If yes, how can I do it?
It's not necessary that it will be a txt file. Just a way to pass different values to one parameter.

*Important: I'm using blazemeter plugin for chrome.*

Thanks a lot,
appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). It is very easy to use for parameterizing variables in the test plan.

Check [this article on blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) to understand the CSV Data Set Config quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can go for:

1. [HTML Link Parser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser). See [Poll Example](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example) which shows how you can use it for selecting random values from inputs
2. You can extract all the possible values from the previous response using a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), most probably [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) and configure each thread to use its own (or random) value from the input
3. And last, but not the least, you can use an external data source like .txt or .csv file and utilize [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each thread (virtual user) would read the next value from file instead of using recorded hard-coded values.